# Submit Button Missing Highlight

Tags: html, asp.net

I have several forms throughout my web app that have a 'submit' and a 'cancel' button.  The submit buttons works fine and is properly used as the default button when the user presses enter.  However, in newer versions of IE the submit button isn't shown with the typical highlight that indicates its the default button.

I found I can use the following to show the highlight.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

However, I don't really want to force it to use older standards.  Plus the highlight still isn't shown in Firefox.

What do I need to do to show this highlight?

Thanks

Comment: That makes the page that is best for the IE7 it has nothing to do with the CSS it won't add CSS properties to the browser..

Comment: Right. It makes the page best for IE7 by telling newer versions of IE to use it's older less standards compliant rules for interpreting CSS.  In any case, I still need a way to get the highlight to show in IE, Firefox, and Chrome.